# How to commonly use a storyboard's view component?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, storyboard

I have a storyboard with a view controller(`Menu View Controller`), in which if the navigation bar’s menu button is pressed, a menu like view slides into the screen. I achieved this by animating the `trailing` constraint of the `left menu view`, from 0 to a value and vice-in-versa.

The storyboard looks like,

[image]

Now, by this method I have a slide-in slide-out menu view,

end result is like,

[image]

now what if I need to use it as a common component in more than one view controllers?

Can I have this `menu view controller` in a separate storyboard and then refer it from my another view controller?

Should I include the left menu view in every view controllers or is there any other smart ways to achieve this?

Comment: Typically you would set up the menu as a container view controller and have it load the various content view controllers

Comment: It is worth noting that Apple recommends against these sorts of menus even though they are popular

Comment: why is that? do you mean the sort of customised menu, like the one I'm using here or do you mean this type of sliding menus in general?

Comment: This type of sliding menu. It was covered in a wwdc session in 2014 http://blog.manbolo.com/2014/06/30/apple-on-hamburger-menus

Comment: Yes, but they accept such controllers in our apps, I'd previously used it in one of my live applications before, with the help of SWRevealviewcontroller. Now, I just need a way to do it myself, to match the client requirement.

Comment: Yes, it isn't "forbidden"

Comment: Ofcourse it's not.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend checking out [this AppCoda tutorial](http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-sidebar-navigation-menu/). This tutorial explains how to use the [SWRevealViewController](https://github.com/John-Lluch/SWRevealViewController), which is a "A UIViewController subclass for revealing a rear (left and/or right) view controller behind a front controller". Both the Github page and the AppCoda tutorial explain on how to implement this side menu. This solution is super simple and very reusable!

UPDATE: Added more context around the external link.

Comment: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.

Answer (score 0):

Use MMDrawer controller library which is best suitable for you and easy to integrate. Which can provide you left drawer and right drawer and which you can use in multiple controller.

Also you can manage these 2 components in 2 different VC so it will be easy to manage code.

To integrate follow this link:

https://github.com/mutualmobile/MMDrawerController